# Variable declaration necessary in for loop?

Tags: javascript, keyword

What is the difference between:

- `for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {}`
- `for (i=0; i<5; i++) {}`

And is it necessary to include the var keyword?

I understand that the var keyword affects variable scope, but I'm having trouble understanding if it's necessary to include the keyword in for loops.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Comment: JavaScript does not have block scope for variables. So putting `var` inside or outside of a loop does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example, your variable is defined globally, so if you're in the browser environment, you can access it from the `window` object.

The first one is an equivalent of:

```
var i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {}
```

as all the variables in javascript are hoisted to the beginning of the scope.

Comment: Thanks Andrusie! So in most cases it is absolutely necessary to include the var keyword when creating a for loop, right?

Comment: If not declared and without `use strict` It will be [`hoisted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Also, `window` object exists only inside browser.

Comment: yes, it is recommended not to pollute the global scope; you can try to use some type checkers like jshint or jslint - they'll give you some warnings about such code

Comment: it's also good to use the strict mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: @PM77-1: you're right with `window` object, I shouldn't simplify that much; but "if not declared and without use strict It will be hoisted. " -> are you sure? if you use `use strict` then it throws an error, otherwise it's defined in the global scope IMHO

Comment: I made a too broad of a statement regarding `hoisting`.  You're correct.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**2**

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**3**

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**1** and **2** are the same.

**3** you probably never mean to do — it puts `i` in the global scope.

Comment: @Tommy see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming your are using C#, Java or JavaScript.  The short answer is you need the var if "i" has not already been declared.  You do not need if it has already been declared.

For example:

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {}
```

Now there may be some implicit variable typing depending on language and IDE, but relying on implicit typing can be difficult to maintain.

Hope this helps, good luck!